# React hook using useEffect with an array inside the dependencies array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook and inside I'm doing this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dimensions.forEach(dimension => {
    dimension.filterFunction(...);
  });
}, [ dimensions, endDate, startDate ]);
```

the problem is that this runs every time because I'm passing a new `dimensions` array. In the parent if I do `const dimensions = useMemo(() => [ dimension ], [ dimension ])` it fixes it. But is there a way I can prevent this from inside my custom hook?

Comment: Is the issue that the `useEffect` triggers when it is passed the *same* `dimensions` array, as in the contents have not changed? Because `useEffect` cannot perfom equality checks on arrays - you've basically added the equality check in with `useMemo`, which seems like a reasonable solution. The only other way I can think of is to store the previous value of `dimensions` and manually check it, which seems like it would be much less elegant. Also, FYI, useEffect is not a custom hook.

Comment: Can you please clarify "runs every time"? Always runs on render?

Comment: @LawrenceWitt thanks, I'll check that solution. I know `useEffect` is not a custom hook. I'm using it _inside_ my custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing dimensions as a parameter to a function wrapping your `useEffect()` and removing it from the array that's the second argument to useEffect?

```
    const useDimensions = (dimensions) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            dimensions.forEach(dimension => {
                dimension.filterFunction(...);
            });
        }, [ endDate, startDate ]);
    };
```

That should keep it from re-rendering and you should be able to call it whenever you need to.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie Thanks for the edit...it's been a long day.

Comment: If later I want to do `const dimensions = useDimensions()`, shouldn't this `return dimensions`? thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get an idea of how you're using the results from your code sample.